# Using return value of object function in a string

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do some logic inside of a JavaScript object to determine what the value should be, and am running into some difficulty.

I have a 'config' object:

```
var gRestfulServicesHost = new function() {
   return {
     hostUrlPrefix: 'http://',
     hostUrl: 'somehost.example.com',
     hostVitalSourceGPOUrl: 'local.somehost.com/restful',
     relativePathUI: '/application',
     relativePathRestfulSvc: function() {
      if(oGetVars.env) {
        switch (oGetVars.env) {
           case 'dev':
              console.warn('Using dev restful service');
              break;
           case 'qa':
              console.warn('Using qa restful service');
              break;
          case 'release':
             console.warn('Using release restful service');
             break;
          case 'staging':
             console.warn('Using staging restful service');
             break;
          case 'demo':
             console.warn('Using demo restufl service');
             break;
          default:
             console.warn('Using local restful service');
             break;
          }
       }
       return '/some-provider/api';
    }
  }
};
```

But then when I go to retrieve the values, something like this works just fine:

```
gRestfulServicesHost.hostUrlPrefix // inspector shows 'http://'
```

But when I want to use `relativePathRestfulSvc`, like this:

```
gRestfulServicesHost.relativePathRestfulSvc // inspector shows: function () { ... }
```

I want the return value of the function, but it's like the function isn't even being eval'd. I've even tried it with the parens `gRestfulServicesHost.relativePathRestfulSvc()` but it still doesn't work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're not actually calling the function, you're assigning a function to the `relativePathRestfulSvc` property. To actually run the code, you must do this:

```
relativePathRestfulSvc: (function() {
  if(oGetVars.env) {
    switch (oGetVars.env) {
       case 'dev':
          console.warn('Using dev restful service');
          break;
       case 'qa':
          console.warn('Using qa restful service');
          break;
      case 'release':
         console.warn('Using release restful service');
         break;
      case 'staging':
         console.warn('Using staging restful service');
         break;
      case 'demo':
         console.warn('Using demo restufl service');
         break;
      default:
         console.warn('Using local restful service');
         break;
      }
   }
   return '/some-provider/api';
})()
```

Notice that the whole function has been wrapped in parentheses `()`, and then is immediately called (the following `()`), which will assign the return value of the function to the `relativePathRestfulSvc` property.

This pattern is known as "Immediately Invoked Function Expression" (IIFE, pronounced "iffy"), and generally takes the form of `(function() { ... })()`, where a function is declared and is immediately called/invoked.

You can read up about it here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression

Answer (score 1):

You're not actually *calling* the function anywhere.  You'd want something like:

```
relativePathRestfulSvc: (function() {
      if(oGetVars.env) {
        switch (oGetVars.env) {
           case 'dev':
              console.warn('Using dev restful service');
              break;
           case 'qa':
              console.warn('Using qa restful service');
              break;
          case 'release':
             console.warn('Using release restful service');
             break;
          case 'staging':
             console.warn('Using staging restful service');
             break;
          case 'demo':
             console.warn('Using demo restufl service');
             break;
          default:
             console.warn('Using local restful service');
             break;
          }
       }
       return '/some-provider/api';
    })() // <--- Use () to call the function
```